# FCM returns error : NotRegistered after the first message

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the instructions on firebase.google.com to add FCM in my project. 
Everything was fine, I've got the message "FirebaseApp initialization successful" and fresh token in my logs. But It's not working... Only the first push notification that I send to the token I get success. The second push and rest get error "NotRegistered". 
Documentation says

> If it is NotRegistered, you should remove the registration ID from your server database because the application was uninstalled from the device, or the client app isn't configured to receive messages.

but application wasn't removed and client app is configured to receive messages because the first message comes to the client

Comment: Check if the `onTokenRefresh()` method is being called. This means that the token is updated and you have to use the new token.
Are you using the firebase console to send the notification? or you are using your own server implementation.

Comment: GeorgeLBA , onTokenRefresh in my case is called only once at the first start of programm or after cleaning all apps data. I'm using my own server implementation

Comment: Nikita, Try printing the token after you send the first notification. Just to make sure that the token is not changing. Use `FirebaseInstanceID.getToken()` and verify if the token is the same after you send the notification. If it is null is because the token was removed for some reason.

Comment: I have same problem... FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() return same token which is on the server. When I tested on my machine with curl so result is "NotRegistered"

Comment: Any insights on this? I have the same issue.

Comment: We have been getting this in Firebase for web esp in case of chrome

Comment: facing same issue .. anyone solved this?

Comment: it's happening to me too

Answer (score 3):

I struggled for hours but I found the problem. It was really hard to find and explain as well. I'll try:

My project has a dependency with another dependency inside that: 
`My project > Dependency > Sub-dependency`

The sub-dependency contains an `AndroidManifest.xml` file with `<application>` tag. Something like that:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my_sub_library">

    <application android:allowBackup="true">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Because of this application tag, my dependency needed to do it:

```
<manifest package="br.com.ilhasoft.support.databinding"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application tools:node="replace"/>
</manifest>
```

My solution was to update sub-dependency by removing the application tag and update dependency removing the replace action.

Somehow, firebase was ignoring my `FirebaseMessagingService` and revoking my FCM registration token.

I suggest you check your dependencies to see which one has application tag and update/replace it. It worked for me!

Comment: Isn't that 'sub-dependency' in an npm package? If it is, how did you updated it?

Comment: I got a crash when I used `replace` in the application tag.